# Return SAML Token with custom class from MVC4 WebApi STS

Tags: wif, saml, asp.net-web-api

I'm totally new WIF and SAML so would be pleased to see close to my task links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest checking http://www.leastprivilege.com/ as Dominick Baier is the expert.